# Check User/mailbox have Public Folders Root Permission/Permission Level using Redemption

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

How can I check that a user can access Public Folder(Have Public Folders Root Permission/Permission Level) or not, Using Redemption ?
I am using following method to access Public Folders. I want to abort this process if user have not Public Folders access rights.

set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon("Profile","Password", covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional)
set Stores = Session.GetStores()set Store = Stores.FindExchangePublicFoldersStore()
set Folder = Store.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
set folders = Folder.GetFolders()

Thanks

Comment: Use the RDOFolder.ACL collection - see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOACL.htm